# RxJS5 - Operator to convert object map to array

Tags: angular, rxjs5

I have a service that returns an object map which is then used in Angular's `ngFor` which only takes arrays. So, I am using the map operator with lodash's _toArray to convert the data to an array.

Although this works, I then have to import lodash everywhere I need to do this and it seems brittle. I was going to look into creating a custom operator, but perhaps there is an operator that already does this? I can't seem to find the right one(s)

Data:

```json
{ 0 : {data : 'lorem'}, 1 : {data : 'lorem'}, 2 : {data : 'lorem'} }
```

Current:

```js
this.http
    .get('/api')
    .map(data => _.toArray(data));
```

Possible?

```js
this.http
    .get('/api')
    .mapToArray();
```

Comment: You could use Angular in-built `filter` for this. Then you need import lodash only once into where your filter is defined.  https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should be able to do what you want with RxJS's `map` operator and just the `Object.keys()` method.

```js
Rx.Observable
  .of({
    0: { data : 'lorem' },
    1: { data : 'lorem' },
    2: { data : 'lorem' }
  })
  .map(data => Object.keys(data).map(k => data[k]))
  .subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.0.3/dist/global/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That won't necessarily output an array with the elements in the correct order.

Comment: Did I miss where the op wanted the array in a specific order? The reason I answered similar but different is for that exact reason. No need to code for specs that just aren't there.

Comment: I did not need the array in order and this is a good alternative, which is what I was asking for. Thank-you

Comment: Keeping the order of the attributes is tricky, basically, the only guaranteed way of doing it is to define a different array with the expected order and then reorder your result, read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38218582/1657465)