# How to transform Observable coming from a service to an Array to ngFor in Angular2?

Tags: angular, observable

I have a problem with returns types.
Here is my problem :
First my data structure is:     `{"categoryName":"Google","id":"58591d2b7672d99910497bec","clientId":"585808f6737f6aad1985eab2"},{"categoryName":"Yahoo","id":"58591d4c7672d99910497bef","clientId":"585808f6737f6aad1985eab2"},{"categoryName":"Msn","id":"585d25f6ae4b2ecb056bc514","clientId":"585808f6737f6aad1985eab2"}`

I have an HTML file that contains:

```
<tr *ngFor="let category of categories; let id = index">
                        <td>
                            <label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-data-table__select"
                                   for="row[3]">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="row[3]" class="mdl-checkbox__input"/>
                            </label>
                        </td>
                        <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric"><a [routerLink]="['/category/links']"></a>{{
                            category.categoryName }}
                        </td>
                        <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">{{category.categoryName}}</td>
                         <td #category.id><i (click)="deleteCategory(id)" class="material-icons">delete</i></td>
                    </tr>
```

The component is as below (I only write here ngOnInit() ):

```
ngOnInit(): void
    {
        this.categoryService.getCategories().subscribe((data) => {
               this.categories=data;
                console.log("data inside component" + data);
            }
        )
            //console.log(JSON.stringify(this.categories));
    //        .map((data) =>
    //        {
    //            this.categories=data;
    //        })
    }
```

and the service is:

```
getCategories(){
        return this.category.find({where: {clientId: this.userApi.getCurrentId()}}).map((data) => {

            console.log("type of data: "+ typeof(data));

            console.log ("data:" + JSON.stringify(data));
            //return data;
        }, err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    };
```

If I do a console.log from the service, the data is shown. If I do a console.log from the component, nothing is shown : the message is:

```
data inside componentundefined
```

as if the "data" is not passed from the Service to the Component, not passed, or not from the correct type.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance and best regards

Comment: I think you are not returning an observable from your service.

Comment: For your question in the title check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41865471/rxjs5-operator-to-convert-object-map-to-array, and you posted commented //return data; in your service's map operator.. without that, your Observable is not returning anything... I assume that was an oversight?

Comment: ok that is fine. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uncomment return in `map` statement. because you do not return anything after do map on data, you got `undefined` return.

```
getCategories() {
   return this.category.find({where: {clientId: this.userApi.getCurrentId()}}).map((data) => {

     console.log("type of data: "+ typeof(data));

     console.log ("data:" + JSON.stringify(data));
     return data; // uncomment this line
   }, err => {
      console.log(err);
   });
};
```